# If $\sum a_n z^n$ has $r \gt 0$ then there is a $C \gt 0$ such that if $A \gt 1/r$ then $|a_n| \le CA^n$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Suppose that $\sum a_n z^n$ has a radius of convergence greater than $0$. Then there exists a positive number $C$ such that if $A \gt 1/r$ (where $r$ is the radius of convergence) then

$$|a_n|\le CA^n \; \text{for all} \; n.$$

Let $s=1/A$ then $0 \lt s \lt r$. Then for all $n$, $\sum |a_n|s^n$ converges so $|a_n|s^n$ is bounded, but I cannot show that there is a $C$ that bounds the sequence for all $A \gt 1/r$. How can I solve this problem?
I would greatly appreciate any help.

This is a Theorem from Lang's Complex Analysis, and this result is also used in proving that the product of convergent power series is convergent.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not true in general. $\sum n\,z^n$ has radius of convergence $1$. Given $A>1$, there exists $C>0$ such that $n\le C\,A^n$ for all $n$. If $C$ were independent of $A$, letting $A\to1$ we would have $n\le1$ for all $n$ which is clearly false. In general, the constant $C$ will depend on $A$.

Comment: Yes I see your argument, but this is a theorem from Lang's textbook and he uses this fact to prove another important theorem. Is this wrong altogether?

Comment: In the proof of the theorem Lang first fixes $s<r$ and then gets $C$. The corollary should be stated : given $A>1/r$ there exists $C>0$ ...